# Does anyone know of a wireless N card that works out of the box?

Tags: wireless, networking

So far I have tried:

- Tenda W322P
- Addon ADD-NWP210

Neither work on Meerkat. Both worked out the box with windows 7.

Comment: if your card is USB running on a terminal the command `lsusb`, if your card is PCI running `lspci` and update your post with this information for each card.

Answer (score 4):

This is an attempt to create a, more or less complete listing of wireless devices with information about the chipset they are based on and whether or not they are supported in Linux., there are places where you can find this kind of information :

1. [Linux Wireless wiki](http://linuxwireless.org/)
2. [Linux wireless LAN support](http://linux-wless.passys.nl/?lang=english)
3. [* WifiDocs * WirelessCardsSupported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)

Answer (score 2):

I got a Dlink DWA-556. It works out of the box; just put it in and start up and it works.

I set it up in master mode as an AP with hostapd, and not all cards can do that. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I went out and bought an Atheros card when I heard they released their drivers as GPL.

The FSF also has a listing of free software supported cards, which includes the atheros: http://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/net/wireless/index_html/cards.html

If the FSF, with their strict freedom requirements, can get behind a card, then you can bet the card will be free-as-in-speech and decently supported.  Free driver supported hardware is easier to get support in linux.